# setTimeout Execute continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function map_vehicle(vid) {

    function exe_map(){
         alert(vid);
    }
    var timer = setTimeout(exe_map,10000);
}
```

this is my javascript code. i want `alert(vid)` to execute every 10000 milisec without using **setIntrval** and `inner map_vehicle` function.
thank you.

Comment: because i'm get 'vid' from datatable onclick function. i'm already try it setIntrval,but i have select 2nd row of datatable then value 'vid' show 1st row value then show 2nd row value

Answer (score 1):

> i want alert(vid) execute every 10000 milisec without using
>   setIntrval and inner map_vehicle function.

Just call the same `setTimeout` again within `exe_map`

```
function map_vehicle(vid)
{
    function exe_map()
    {
         alert(vid);
         setTimeout(exe_map,10000);//observe this line
    }
    setTimeout(exe_map,10000);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function map_vehicle(vid)
{
    function exe_map()
    {
         alert(vid);
         setTimeout(exe_map,3000);//observe this line
    }
    setTimeout(exe_map,3000);
}

map_vehicle("10");
```

Comment: i have already try this method, the alert msg execute couple of time

Comment: i'm get 'vid' from datatable tr onclick function

Comment: @Tamil I have attached a demo with 3 sec timeout. It gives me `vid` value as many number of times as I need. Ensure that you refresh the browser to stop alerting.

Comment: @Tamil Glad to help! Accept and Upvote the answer that has helped you.